# Analytic gradient of softmax on CS231n

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I had a particular question regarding the gradient for the softmax used in the CS231n.  After deriving the softmax function to calculate the gradient for each individual class, the authors divide the gradient by the num_examples, even though the gradient is not summed anywhere.  What is the logic behind this.  Why can't we just use the softmax gradients directly?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A typical objective of a neural network learning is to minimise an **expected** loss over data distribution, thus:

```
minimise E_{x,y} L(x,y)
```

now, in practise we use an estimate of this quantity, which is given by a sample mean, for a training set xi, yi

```
minimise 1/N SUM L(xi, yi)
```

what is given in the above derivation is d L(xi, yi) / d theta, but since we want to minimise 1/N SUM L(xi, yi) we should compute its gradient, which is:

```
d 1/N SUM L(xi, yi) / d theta = 1/N SUM d L(xi, yi) / d theta
```

This is just a property of partial derivatives (derivative of the sum being a sum of derivatives and so on). Notice, that in all the above derivations author talks about Li, while the actual optimisation is performed over L (notice lack of index i), which is defined as L = 1/N SUM_i Li